# Accurev: easy way to defunct entire directory tree

Tags: directory, accurev, defunct

Is there an quick way to defunct (and then promote) a directory and everything below it in Accurev?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, defunct just the directory and promote.

You do not defunct its content.  If you do, you will strand all those files once the root level directory is promoted.